# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null. for displaying total quantity of items in my Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am having problems in displaying total number of items in my shopping-cart.I am getting data from firebase as an object and use one of its properties to get i.e 'quanity' to get total quanity of items and then displaing it on the ShoppingCart badge on my top navbar.

### shopping-cart.service.ts

```
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AdminProducts } from './models/admin-products';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { ShoppingCart } from './models/shopping-cart';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {  
 

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase)  {
  }

  private create(){
    return this.db.list('/shopping-cart').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

  async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db
        .object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges()
          .pipe(map((x:any) => new ShoppingCart(x.items))); // Error: Cannot read property 'items' of null.
  }

  private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId(): Promise<string> {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;

  }    

   addToCart(product: AdminProducts){
    this.updateQuantity(product, 1);
  }

  removeFromCart(product: AdminProducts){
    this.updateQuantity(product, -1);
  }

  async updateQuantity(product: AdminProducts, change: number){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item) => {
      if (item) {
        item$.update({quantity: item['quantity'] + change});
      } else {
        item$.set({ product, quantity: 1 });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

### shopping-cart.ts

```
import { ShoppingCartItem } from './shopping-cart-item';

export class ShoppingCart {
  items :ShoppingCartItem[];

 

 constructor(public itemsMap: { [productId:string]: ShoppingCartItem }) {
  this.itemsMap = itemsMap || {};
   for (let productId in itemsMap)
   this.items.push(itemsMap[productId]);
 }
 

  get totalItemCount(){
   let count = 0;
   for (let productId in this.itemsMap)
      count += this.itemsMap[productId].quantity;
    return count;  
  }
}
```

---

### shopping-cart-item.ts

```
import { AdminProducts } from "./admin-products";

export interface ShoppingCartItem {
  products: AdminProducts;
  quantity: number;
}
```

---

### top-navbar.component

```
import { ShoppingCartService } from './../shopping-cart.service';
import { AutheService } from './../services/authe.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingCart } from '../models/shopping-cart';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'top-navbar',
  templateUrl: './top-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-navbar.component.css']
})
export class TopNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  cart$: Observable<ShoppingCart>;

  constructor(public authe: AutheService, private cartService: ShoppingCartService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit(){
    this.cart$ = await this.cartService.getCart();
  }
  logout(){
  this.authe.logout();
  }
}
```

---

### top-navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">TheStore</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <ng-template #anonymousUser>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">login</a>
          </li>
        </ng-template>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">
            Shopping Cart
            <span class="badge bg-warning text-dark badge-pill" *ngIf="cart$  | async as cart">
              {{ cart.totalItemCount}}
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li ngbDropdown *ngIf = "authe.user$ | async as user; else anonymousUser" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            {{user.displayName}}</a>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders">Manage Orders</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products">Manage Products</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)= "logout()">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>      
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Comment: Check the response of your getCart() request. If the first response is returning null (because a '/shopping-carts/' + cartId document still doesn't exist), you need to add a check...like 'x ? new ShoppingCart(x.items) : undefined'

Comment: getting an object in console which has some properties.

Comment: So, I don’t really know the realtime database (I use firestore)...but if it’s similar, the valueChanges() emits values every time...maybe the first value is returning null, breaking the code...one thing: avoid using ‘any’ (like on the pipe)...it makes things harder